# How to get a value with leading zero's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
ID (NVarchar Column)

01 
02
03
...
```

Query

```
Select max(id) from table1
```

Ouput is

```
3
```

I want to get maximum id with leading zero, if it is 002 means, the query should return 002

Expected Output is

```
03
```

How to do this

Need Query Help

Comment: What is the type of the `ID` column?

Comment: `Select max(id) from table1` **will not** give `3` if it is stored as `03` in a varchar column. MAX gives the same retrun type as the expression being MAXed. Please give correct information if you want answers

Comment: This makes no difference. MAX(nvarchar) = nvarchar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933240(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the idea:    `Select right('000' + max(id),2) from table1`

Answer (score 3):

I executed the following piece of code:

```
 DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
            ID nvarchar(10)
            )

 INSERT @TABLE VALUES ( '003' )
 INSERT @TABLE VALUES ( '004' )

 SELECT MAX (ID)

 FROM @TABLE
```

The output was

```
  004
```

When using the data type as int however:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
            ID int
            )

INSERT @TABLE  values ( '003' )
INSERT @TABLE VALUES ( '004')

SELECT MAX (ID )

FROM @TABLE
```

The output was:

```
4
```

I would check you have your data types defined correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as following:

```
declare @input int, @len int
set @len = 2
select right(REPLICATE('0',@len)+convert(varchar(5),2),@len ) AS LPAD
```

I am assuming that you know the length all the time. You can make it a UDF as well.

Comment: Should be no need of the columnn is varchar: question is incorrect and/or incomplete so we can't answer it

Comment: right. But the max() will perform differently when the table is nvarchar

Comment: no, it won't as per MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933240(SQL.80).aspx Now -1